# Schedule sails lift

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Is there anyway to schedule sails lift ? (every 12 hours for example sails restarts)
The reason why I am trying to do this, is because I keep loosing connection to the remote database.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try to **fix the issue with connection to database** ? :)

About your question, you can modify `app.js` file with following contents:

```
var Sails = require('sails');
var cron = require('node-cron');
var sails;

function startServer() {
  if (sails) {
    sails.lower(_onServerLower);
  } else {
    Sails.lift({}, _onServerStarted);
  }
}

function _onServerStarted(error, server) {
  sails = server;
}

function _onServerLower(error) {
  sails = null;
  startServer();
}

new cron.CronJob('* * */12 * * *', startServer, null, true);
```

**But, really. Maybe you should fix issue with connection ? :)**